Karate Framework: Passing a file or data in any form larger then 50 kb
I am new to karate framework.
My test case is I need to send a Post request where I need to send a file/data of more then 50kb in the header and record the response.
I am unable to find a way.
This might be a very basic question but its important for me to learn.
Thanks in advance.

Karate has no limit to what you can put in the header, but your server may be a different matter. You can always do this:
* header foo = read('myfile.txt')

Please refer to the documentation for explanations of header and read() if needed.
